# How to use VAST IMA google ads with Jwplayer in android

Tags: android, jwplayer, vast, google-ima

Does JWPlayer support Ima VAST ads type in Android?

Answer (score 2):

JW Player does support IMA VAST ads in Android, but there are a few clarifications:

1.) You do need a JW Player (paid) license that supports serving ads. Alternatively, we do offer a Developer program, a trial-period which allows you to serve VAST ads (see https://www.jwplayer.com/pricing/) for no cost.

2.) The Android device would need a supported browser if you are using the [HTML5 Player](https://support.jwplayer.com/articles/browser-support). Or, if you are using the SDK's, the Android device must be: 4.1+ (API level 16) (see Requirements [here](https://developer.jwplayer.com/sdk/android/docs/developer-guide/)).

As for documentation, you can refer to [this](https://developer.jwplayer.com/sdk/android/docs/developer-guide/advertising/enable-google-ima/) document for the SDK, [this](https://beta-developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/jw8-monetize-your-content) document for custom configuration for the HTML5 Player, or [this](https://support.jwplayer.com/articles/how-to-schedule-ad-breaks) document for configuring through our Dashboard.